# How to interact with ag-Grid using TestCafe

Tags: testing, automated-tests, ag-grid, e2e-testing, testcafe

I want to interact with ag-Grid data using TestCafe without any framework like Mocha, Jasmine etc, is there any way?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I checked [the ag-Grid demo page](https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php) and it works properly with TestCafe:

```js
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Fixture`
    .page `https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php`;

test('test', async t => {
    const filterInput       = Selector('#myGrid > div > div.ag-root-wrapper-body.ag-layout-normal.ag-focus-managed > div.ag-root.ag-unselectable.ag-layout-normal > div.ag-header.ag-focus-managed.ag-pivot-off > div.ag-header-viewport > div > div.ag-header-row.ag-header-row-floating-filter > div:nth-child(1) > div.ag-floating-filter-body > div > input');
    const selectAllCheckbox = Selector('#ag-input-id-63');

    const cellTonySmith     = Selector('#myGrid').find('span').withText('Tony Smith');
    const checkboxTonySmith = cellTonySmith.parent().child(1);

    const cellTonyGunner     = Selector('#myGrid').find('span').withText('Tony Gunner');
    const checkboxTonyGunner = cellTonyGunner.parent().child(1);

    await t
        .typeText(filterInput, 'Tony')
        .hover(cellTonySmith)
        .click(checkboxTonySmith)
        .hover(cellTonyGunner)
        .click(checkboxTonyGunner);

    await t
        .debug();
});
```

**UPD**:

> I want to click on the name that belongs to English language

```js
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Fixture`
    .page `https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php`;

test('test', async t => {
    const englishCells = Selector('div').withAttribute('col-id', 'language').withText('English');

    const firstEnglishCell              = englishCells.nth(0);
    const nameRelatedToFirstEnglishCell = firstEnglishCell.parent().child(0).child(0).child(-1);

    const secondEnglishCell              = englishCells.nth(1);
    const nameRelatedToSecondEnglishCell = secondEnglishCell.parent().child(0).child(0).child(-1);

    await t
        .click(nameRelatedToFirstEnglishCell)
        .click(nameRelatedToSecondEnglishCell)
        .debug();
});
```

Comment: Thank you response. I want to deal with specific column's value in the ag-grid, for e.g I want to click on the name that belongs to English language, can you please advice how to iterate through the ag-grid in such case? Thanks